# Connect dynamic array of search terms to string in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Using Laravel 5.3 and MySQL 5.7.17.
I store text in a TEXT column (don't know the limit).

**I want to search this text for different variations of different words in different languages that should lead to the same match.

Example:**

```
'bird' -> bird

'Vogel' -> bird

'pájaro' -> bird
```

Try #1:
Set up a table with two columns:

- c1 containing the string 'bird'
- c2 containing a serialized array with all alternative search terms. Then, search the large text for all alternative search strings of the unserialized array.

Advantage: only need one table 
Disadvantage: serialize and unserialize data all the time - bad performance?

Try#2: Set up two tables, one containing the real, right search terms I am gonna use for my code. The second containing all alternative search terms that are linked via a 'One to Many' relationship in Laravel.

Then search for all terms in the second table and, if found, give me a match for the corresponding real string in the first.

Advantage: probably better performance
Disadvantage: two different tables.

Since I am dealing with words that don't always have a close connection to each other, I can't rely on stuff like **spell checker.**

want to manage library of the alternative search terms manually anyway. Is there a better solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about 1 table:

- c1 contains an indexed list of the possible search terms
- c2 contains the standardised search term

I guess that VARCHAR would support better indexing than TEXT. Is there an upper limit that you could impose (50 characters? 100 characters?)?

```
| c1       | c2         |
|----------+------------|
| bird     | bird       |
| vogel    | bird       |
```

Comment: That will definitely do the job. I thought so much about it that I didn't see that solution. Thanks!